# How to change "to-reply" property of email in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am able to send emails in alfresco using Java API but I am not able to change the "Reply-to: " property like this in alfresco :

```
Message replyMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
replyMessage = (MimeMessage) message.reply(false);
replyMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(to));
replyMessage.setText("Thanks");
replyMessage.setReplyTo(message.getReplyTo());
```

> replyMessage.setReplyTo(message.getReplyTo());

This is my code to send emails

```
         NodeRef companyHome = repository.getCompanyHome();

         List<String> pathElements = new ArrayList<>();
            pathElements.add("Data Dictionary");
            pathElements.add("Email Templates");
            pathElements.add("Trams Email Templates");
            pathElements.add("CONTENT_NOTIFICATION.html.ftl");

            FileInfo templateFile;
            try {
                templateFile = serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService()
                        .resolveNamePath(companyHome, pathElements);
                NodeRef template = templateFile.getNodeRef();
                List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
             users.add(userName);
             ActionService actionService = serviceRegistry.getActionService();
             Action mailAction = actionService.createAction(MailActionExecuter.NAME);
                mailAction.setParameterValue(MailActionExecuter.PARAM_TEMPLATE, template);
                Map<String, Serializable> templateArgs = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();

                templateArgs.put("userName", userName);

                Map<String, Serializable> templateModel = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
                templateModel.put("args",(Serializable)templateArgs);
                mailAction.setParameterValue(MailActionExecuter.PARAM_TEMPLATE_MODEL,(Serializable)templateModel);
             mailAction.setParameterValue(MailActionExecuter.PARAM_SUBJECT, "Content Notification");
             mailAction.setParameterValue(MailActionExecuter.PARAM_TO_MANY, (Serializable) users);
            actionService.executeAction(mailAction, null);

            } catch (org.alfresco.service.cmr.model.FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Is there any way to enable this replyTo parameter in alfresco ?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have override the OOTB MailActionExecuter class.
added my code to set the replyTo parameter
I fixed parameter from java class `mailAction.setParameterValue(MailActionExecuter.PARAM_REPLY_TO,"myEmail@gmail.com");`

and access using

```
public static final String PARAM_REPLY_TO = "reply_to";

message.setReplyTo(replyTo);
```